# laravel remove duplicate from table best way

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have one table and want to remove duplicate in laravel using DB:: not eloquent

my tables name is sale_details and fields are

```
id,orderId,shop,user,item,quantity,price,total
```

where orderId,shop,user,item are unique

I want to delete rows where orderId,shop,user,item are duplicate based on these 4 fields, not one.

how can I do it the best way?

Answer (score 2):

The best option would be to add an index on your table :

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE sale_details ADD UNIQUE (orderId,shop,user,item);
```

With IGNORE, only the first found row is kept, and the others are removed.
You should keep this UNIQUE if you don't want future duplicates, if not, you can  drop it just after.